# Sending POST from Android Application

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm triyng to send POST request to the server. The following java code working for PC application, but doesn't work on my Android application. The Iternet permission is added, so, what I have to do to send this post, and what other methods and libraries I have to use to replace this code for Android?

```
      String hostname = "xxxxxxx.box"; 
      int port = 80;
      InetAddress  addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
      Socket sock = new Socket(addr, port); 
      String SID = new classSID("xxxxxx").obtainSID();
      BufferedWriter  wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
      String str = "enabled=on&username="+givenName+"&email="+givenEmail+"&password="+givenPassword+"&frominternet=on&box_admin_rights=on&phone_rights=on&homeauto_rights=on&uid=&sid="+SID+"&apply=";

       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       wr.write("POST /system/boxuser_edit.lua HTTP/1.1");
       wr.write("Host: xxxxxx:80" + "\r\n");
       wr.write("Accept: text/html"  + "\r\n");
       wr.write("Keep-Alive: 300" + "\r\n"); 
       wr.write("Connection: Keep-Alive"  + "\r\n");
       wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"+"\r\n");
       wr.write("Content-Length: "+str.length()+"\r\n");
       wr.write("\r\n");
       wr.write(str+"\r\n");
       wr.flush();
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////           
       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));  
       String line;  
       while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)  
           Log.v("Response", line);     

       wr.close();
       rd.close();
       sock.close();
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to catch the error, but error does not exist. Just doesn't work.

Comment: Consider using an ip rather than a hostname and test with the code i provided below

Answer (score 1):

Try this: and consider using an IP instead of hostname because your android device might nto be able to resolve a local hostname

```
private static final String     UTF_8       = "UTF-8";
/**
 * @param hostNameOrIP
 *            : the host name or IP<br/>
 * @param webService
 *            : the web service name<br/>
 * @param classOrEndPoint
 *            : the file or end point<br/>
 * @param method
 *            : the method being called<br/>
 * @param parameters
 *            : the parameters to be sent in the message body
 * @return
 */
public static String connectPOST(final String url, final HashMap<String, String> parameters) {
    final StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (null != parameters) {
        for (final HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            if (postDataBuilder.length() != 0) {
                postDataBuilder.append("&");
            }
            postDataBuilder.append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    final StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    InputStreamReader in = null;
    BufferedReader buff = null;
    try {
        final URL page = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) page.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        out = conn.getOutputStream();
        final byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes(UTF_8);
        out.write(postData);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        final int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if ((responseCode == 401) || (responseCode == 403)) {
            // Authorization Error
            Log.e(TAG, "Authorization error in " + url + "(" + postDataBuilder.toString() + ")");
            // throw new Exception("Authorization Error in " + method + "("
            // + postDataBuilder.toString() + ")");
            return null;
        }
        if (responseCode == 404) {
            // Authorization Error
            Log.e(TAG, "Not found error in " + url + "(" + postDataBuilder.toString() + ")");
            // throw new Exception("Authorization Error in " + method + "("
            // + postDataBuilder.toString() + ")");
            return null;
        }

        if ((responseCode >= 500) && (responseCode <= 504)) {
            // Server Error
            Log.e(TAG, "Internal server error in " + url + "(" + postDataBuilder.toString() + ")");
            // throw new Exception("Internal Server Error in " + method +
            // "("
            // + postDataBuilder.toString() + ")");
            return null;
        }
        in = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) conn.getContent());
        buff = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        while ((null != (line = buff.readLine())) && !"null".equals(line)) {
            text.append(line + "\n");
        }
        buff.close();
        buff = null;
        in.close();
        in = null;
        conn.disconnect();
        conn = null;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while connecting to " + url + " with parameters: " + postDataBuilder + ", exception: " + e.toString() + ", cause: "
                + e.getCause() + ", message: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (null != out) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (final IOException e1) {
            }
            out = null;
        }
        if (null != buff) {
            try {
                buff.close();
            } catch (final IOException e1) {
            }
            buff = null;
        }
        if (null != in) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (final IOException e1) {
            }
            in = null;
        }
        if (null != conn) {
            conn.disconnect();
            conn = null;
        }
    }
    final String temp = text.toString();
    if (text.length() > 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Success in " + url + "(" + postDataBuilder.toString() + ") = " + temp);
        return temp;
    }
    Log.w(TAG, "Warning: " + url + "(" + postDataBuilder.toString() + "), text = " + temp);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: p.S. You don't need to specify the port for port 80

Comment: Hello Shereef, can you tell me please where the class Communication comes from, and why (InputStream) throws error? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Sorry fixed, the communications class is my class i removed all references to it

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with creating socket on port 80. You need root permission to access port < 1024 in android. See [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4039)